# Copy a googleMap from the main body inside a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I want to copy an embedded googleMap inside a modal, when a user clicks on a button. The reason is, that want a "fullscreen-mode" of the embedded googlemap. My approach was to clone the googlemaps element from the body and insert this in a fullscreen modal (not provided in the MWE below, to reduce code complexity), which pop ups once the user clicks the button.

The issue is, that simple clone the element, where the googleMap is nested in, isn't sufficient, because for example markers will disappear.

You can find an minimal working example on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/77Q1sccQgU).

Is there another or similar approach or even a code fix of my MWE to show up a googleMap in a Modal without creating a new map instance and so one?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to force a reload of the map after opening the modal.
Something like

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

Comment: I tried to adapt the solution to the provided bootply, but it doesn't work. Did you tried it with the bootply?